# Hibernate implementing soft delete with superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Currently soft delete implementation looks like this

Parent class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ParentClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    private boolean archived = false;
}
```

Child Class 1

```
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE child_class1 SET archived = 1 WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "is_archived = 'false'")
public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Child class 2

```
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE child_class2 SET archived = 1 WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "is_archived = 'false'")
public class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass {
    ...
    ...
}
```

As you can see, SQLDelete & Where clauses are getting repeated with minor difference in query. Is there a way to generalize them and be able to put them in ParentClass? something like

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE <what_would_come_here> SET archived = 1 WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "is_archived = 'false'")
public abstract class ParentClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    private boolean archived = false;
}
```

I did try above changes but hibernate didn't apply these annotations on get or delete entities.

Comment: FWIW "JPA" will not apply those annotations because they are not JPA annotations. They are totally specific to your provider

Comment: Right, replaced JPA with (hibernate) provider in the question.

Comment: @YogeshBadke Did you find anything on this?

Comment: @VivekVardhan sadly nothing yet.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `@MappedSuperclass` with `@Entity`and use `InheritanceStrategy.TABLE_PER_CLASS`?